# XML material transitions for android using Architecture Components Navigation

Tags: android, material-design, android-architecture-components, android-architecture-navigation

Hi I would like to replicate the material design transitions shown [here](https://material.io/design/navigation/navigation-transitions.html#) for top-level and parent-child transitions. I just want the xml files to add as a default NavOptions.